# Language Specific Site, Best Practice

Tags: localization

I'm creating a site to be available in multiple languages.

What's the best way to do this?  Some sites check the browser language setting and redirect to

```
/english_Version/some/path
```

My question is, is there a better way?  Is the /english_Version/ part necessary or can that be hidden away?  What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

The language specific URL is not required, but if you don't use this mechanism, you need some kind of other mechanism to track the user language.

This can be done through cookies, parameters on the URL (other than the directory structure), hidden form fields and other tricks of the trade.

You can also simply look at the browser settings and serve accordingly (without redirection).

However, it is best to give the user a choice in the matter - they might be in a foreign country (think Internet cafe) and want to browse in a different language than that advertised by the browser.

Comment: Agreed. Also, keep in mind that you may want to have different paths depending on the language for SEO purposes, for example the translated version of site.com/en/news might be called site.com/fr/nouvelles . Your system should accomodate that. Most frameworks already come with a ready-made solution; no need to re-invent the wheel.